# How do I make django translate certain files?

Tags: django, internationalization

I'm running `django-admin.py makemessages -l es` from within my app directory to create trnaslation strings. The result includes only those texts that are located in my app directory. My templates directory to that app is located outside the app's directory. How do I ask django to translate my template files too?

I didn't want to run the above command from within the project's dir, because my project contains certain folders that I do not want to translate.

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, I found the answer. You have to create symlinks to the folders you want to get translated (i.e. templaets) and copy those symlinks to you apps directory and run the above command with `--symlinks` included.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly you'll need to use django's `trans` and `blocktrans`
[template tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/internationalization/) to translate certain strings of text.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I am using those template tags. but I'm not able to see translated texts in the generated .po file. That's my problem.